# Creating an API endpoint in a .NET Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, service

I have an ASP.NET project and a .NET Windows service running on the same machine, and I want them to communicate (currently only ASP.NET => Service one way).

The most convenient way to do this (IMO) would be a REST / other API endpoint in the service which the ASP.NET project would call (since ASP.NET works with APIs anyway and they can be protected etc.). The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to do this in a Windows service. Is there a native method / library to support this?

Using .NET Framework 4.5.2 in both projects.

Comment: Btw, if you are developing windows services, take a look at [topshelf](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### .NET Core ERA and beyond

A lot has changed since I wrote this post. .NET (dotnet) Core has become more famous - and we're even already past that; welcome [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/).

Using ASP.NET core makes the task addressed in the question much easier and is the way to go in a new setup or project.

Just create a new project choosing the ASP.NET Core template. It contains templates for API only, MVC, SPA - etc. (or if you want to include pages optionally go for Blazor) and have a look at one of the tutorials mentioned below.

[image]

Documentation for a **Windows service** can be found [here. (host-and-deploy/windows-service)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

If you are using **linux** as host OS - there is an excellent article on how to accomplish the setup: by [Niels Swimberghe](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-run-aspnet-core-as-a-service-on-linux)

---

#### Legacy

As for [ASP.NET Core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) check out [this article](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/aspnet-core-windows-service/)

---

#### Original answer - pre .NET Core (-ish).

There is a library available at nuget:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost

[There is an article on how to use it here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) It's an console app, but easily converted to a windows service.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8080"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Web Server is running.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You will find you will have all common API features, (i.e. controllers, routes, actionfilters) available.

Comment: For anyone reading this, the updated library is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost/, the one linked is legacy.

Comment: @YoavLavi: thanks for the heads-up. I've updated the link.